# APIを28にしたら"Cannot resolve symbol 'NotificationCompat'になりビルドできません。

Tags: android, java

Target version を28に変更したら

> エラー: シンボルを見つけられません　シンボル: クラス NotificationCompat場所: パッケージ android.support.v4.app

となりビルドできなくなりました。

```
android {

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode xx
        versionName "xxx"

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
}
```

Comment: androidXへマイグレーションしてみてはどうでしょうか。ref: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library

Answer (score -1):

APIレベル 28 に対応しているAndroidのバージョンは、9.0 (コードネーム：Pie)ですから、
android.support.v9.app
を使えば解決するかと思います。

android.support.v4.appは、５年余り前の古いバージョンで、サポート切れになっています。
当然、昨年８月にリリースされたPieには対応していません。

Comment: `v4`という名前空間はサポートしている API レベルの意味合い（ただし現在では有名無実化）です。`v9`（API Lv9 までサポートする）のサポートライブラリは存在しないと思います。